# Window function pointer not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some code where I need to call a function when I have it's name in a string. For example:

```
var util = {
    exByName: function(name) {
        window[name](arguments);
    }
};
util.exByName("console.log", "blah");
```

When I run this, the error 'Uncaught TypeError: window[name] is not a function'
however, when I ran this in the browser (Opera):

```
window["console.log"]("blah");
```

It works fine.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Because you can reference nested properties like that. And I know chrome will not work referencing it like that.

Comment: make sure whatever function youre calling is actually in the window scope. if you used a `window.onload` or a `$(function(){...})` then it's not in the window scope.

Comment: @Misaz - of course it is. if it's not in the window scope then accessing it through the window will not work.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. `window["console.log"]("blah");` does not work in chrome... unless someone did `window["console.log"] = console.log.bind(console);`

Comment: @epascarello - that's why i deleted the comment. its the dot notation that breaks it, not the bracket notation. i get what youre saying.

Answer (score 1):

With other browsers and namespaced functions like `console.log` you have to use:

```
window["console"]["log"]("blah")
```

See [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access nested object properties using the dot notation in brackets.

Instead, access different nested levels via separate brackets:

```js
window["console"]["log"]("foo");
```

[More about object property accessors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).